# Parse Excel to JSON

Tags: json, excel, parsing

I would like to know if is posible parse a excel to json. 
And if is possible which is the structure of the excel to make it possible.
There is an application or something??

I have this JSON sructure http://pastie.org/2760828
And I have to insert 500 products and i would like insert into excel and parse them.

Comment: Do you want to go from Excel to JSON or form JSON to Excel? Your question seems to contradict itself.

Comment: sorry for my english.. i want to parse from Excel to Json.
However if is possible Json to excel i like to know how.. to know which structure i need in the excel

Comment: Your question seems to be too broad, please specify additional restrictions you have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**1) First convert your excelsheet to datatable

2) And then convert your datatable to json like below:**

1) conversion excel sheet to datatable

```
string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
Data Source=G:\school pro\schools3.xlsx;
Extended Properties=Excel 5.0";

StringBuilder stbQuery = new StringBuilder();
stbQuery.Append("SELECT top 10 * FROM [A1:M98]");
OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(stbQuery.ToString(), ConnectionString);

DataTable dtSchools = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dtSchools);
```

2) conversion datatable to json

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtSchools)
```

Comment: there some option in php?? I have a host with unix and this code is c#

Comment: Oh!! for that no idea.. but you can do kind of stuff..(start Googling:)

Answer (score 0):

Recently Excel has a Code Editor Plugin which can be used similar to a macro.
This table

[image: Excel code editor and table with user data]

Can be converted to this json

```json
[
    { "Group": "A", "Name": "John", "Age": "21" },
    { "Group": "B", "Name": "Tim", "Age": "24" },
    { "Group": "A", "Name": "Jane", "Age": "28" },
    { "Group": "B", "Name": "Monica", "Age": "26"}
]
```

Using this interface

```js
interface TableData {
    "Group": string;
    "Name": string;
    "Age": string;
}
```

and this code

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook): TableData[] {


    // Get the current, active worksheet and used cells.
    let currentWorksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();    
    let usedRange = currentWorksheet.getUsedRange();    
    console.log(usedRange.getAddress()); // log range address
    // get text
    const texts = usedRange.getTexts();
    // Create an array of JSON objects that match the row structure.
    let returnObjects: TableData[] = [];
    if (usedRange.getRowCount() > 0) {
        returnObjects = returnObjectFromValues(texts);
    }
    // console.log(returnObjects)
    // Log the information and return it for a Power Automate flow.
    console.log(JSON.stringify(returnObjects));
    return returnObjects;
}
```

Above we use the helper function `returnObjectFromValues()`

```js
// function converts 2D array of values into a generic JSON object
// here with TableData object any similar interface would work.
function returnObjectFromValues(values: string[][]): TableData[] {
    let objectArray: TableData[] = [];
    let objectKeys: string[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
            objectKeys = values[i];
            continue;
        }

        let object = {};
        for (let j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
            object[objectKeys[j]] = values[i][j];
        }

        objectArray.push(object as TableData);
    }

    return objectArray;
}
```

And this can be analyzed in sqlite ;-)

```sql
SELECT     
    json_extract(jsonEach.value, '$.Group') as GroupName,
    json_extract(jsonEach.Value, '$.Name') as UserName,
    json_extract(jsonEach.Value, '$.Age') as Age,
    jsonEach.Value as Json_Array_Element
    FROM UserGroup,json_each(UserGroup.JsonArray, '$') as jsonEach;
```

The results looks like this

[image: sqlite json_each and json_exctract on json array]

Answer (score -2):

ExcelToJSON will convert an Excel sheet to JSON format

http://www.exceltojson.com/