# converting excel data to JSON format

Tags: java, python, json, excel

I am trying to convert excel data into JSON format. but the problem is I have excel sheets which are linked to multiple excel sheet. like example root.xlsx which contains 
id, name, phone,department,category,age fields
and where department field refers to  department.xlsx which contains
dname, did, dtype
and category fields refers to category.xlsx which contains 
catid,catname,cattype,

how to convert it to JSON if the data format is like this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Could be a good question if worked out. Maybe post a half working attempt with some example data? Also explain how this is different to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jars Required

```
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
ezmorph-1.0.6.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
poi
```

Sample code

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Header;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.json.Json;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;

import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

public class ReadExcelDataWithDynamicColumn {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // You can specify your excel file path.
        String excelFilePath = "/Users/zhaosong/Documents/WorkSpace/EmployeeInfo.xls";

        // This method will read each sheet data from above excel file and create a JSON and a text file to save the sheet data.
        creteJSONAndTextFileFromExcel(excelFilePath);
    }


    /* Read data from an excel file and output each sheet data to a json file and a text file. 
     * filePath :  The excel file store path.
     * */
    private static void creteJSONAndTextFileFromExcel(String filePath)
    {
        try{
         /* First need to open the file. */
            FileInputStream fInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath.trim());

         /* Create the workbook object to access excel file. */
            //Workbook excelWookBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fInputStream)
         /* Because this example use .xls excel file format, so it should use HSSFWorkbook class. For .xlsx format excel file use XSSFWorkbook class.*/;
            Workbook excelWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fInputStream);

            // Get all excel sheet count.
            int totalSheetNumber = excelWorkBook.getNumberOfSheets();

            // Loop in all excel sheet.
            for(int i=0;i<totalSheetNumber;i++)
            {
                // Get current sheet.
                Sheet sheet = excelWorkBook.getSheetAt(i);

                // Get sheet name.
                String sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();

                if(sheetName != null && sheetName.length() > 0)
                {
                    // Get current sheet data in a list table.
                    List<List<String>> sheetDataTable = getSheetDataList(sheet);

                    // Generate JSON format of above sheet data and write to a JSON file.
                    String jsonString = getJSONStringFromList(sheetDataTable);
                    String jsonFileName = sheet.getSheetName() + ".json";
                    writeStringToFile(jsonString, jsonFileName);

                    // Generate text table format of above sheet data and write to a text file.
                    String textTableString = getTextTableStringFromList(sheetDataTable);
                    String textTableFileName = sheet.getSheetName() + ".txt";
                    writeStringToFile(textTableString, textTableFileName);

                }
            }
            // Close excel work book object. 
            excelWorkBook.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    /* Return sheet data in a two dimensional list. 
     * Each element in the outer list is represent a row, 
     * each element in the inner list represent a column.
     * The first row is the column name row.*/
    private static List<List<String>> getSheetDataList(Sheet sheet)
    {
        List<List<String>> ret = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        // Get the first and last sheet row number.
        int firstRowNum = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
        int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();

        if(lastRowNum > 0)
        {
            // Loop in sheet rows.
            for(int i=firstRowNum; i<lastRowNum + 1; i++)
            {
                // Get current row object.
                Row row = sheet.getRow(i);

                // Get first and last cell number.
                int firstCellNum = row.getFirstCellNum();
                int lastCellNum = row.getLastCellNum();

                // Create a String list to save column data in a row.
                List<String> rowDataList = new ArrayList<String>();

                // Loop in the row cells.
                for(int j = firstCellNum; j < lastCellNum; j++)
                {
                    // Get current cell.
                    Cell cell = row.getCell(j);

                    // Get cell type.
                    int cellType = cell.getCellType();

                    if(cellType == CellType.NUMERIC.getCode())
                    {
                        double numberValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();

                        // BigDecimal is used to avoid double value is counted use Scientific counting method.
                        // For example the original double variable value is 12345678, but jdk translated the value to 1.2345678E7.
                        String stringCellValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(numberValue).toPlainString();

                        rowDataList.add(stringCellValue);

                    }else if(cellType == CellType.STRING.getCode())
                    {
                        String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        rowDataList.add(cellValue);
                    }else if(cellType == CellType.BOOLEAN.getCode())
                    {
                        boolean numberValue = cell.getBooleanCellValue();

                        String stringCellValue = String.valueOf(numberValue);

                        rowDataList.add(stringCellValue);

                    }else if(cellType == CellType.BLANK.getCode())
                    {
                        rowDataList.add("");
                    }
                }

                // Add current row data list in the return list.
                ret.add(rowDataList);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /* Return a JSON string from the string list. */
    private static String getJSONStringFromList(List<List<String>> dataTable)
    {
        String ret = "";

        if(dataTable != null)
        {
            int rowCount = dataTable.size();

            if(rowCount > 1)
            {
                // Create a JSONObject to store table data.
                JSONObject tableJsonObject = new JSONObject();

                // The first row is the header row, store each column name.
                List<String> headerRow = dataTable.get(0);

                int columnCount = headerRow.size();

                // Loop in the row data list.
                for(int i=1; i<rowCount; i++)
                {
                    // Get current row data.
                    List<String> dataRow = dataTable.get(i);

                    // Create a JSONObject object to store row data.
                    JSONObject rowJsonObject = new JSONObject();

                    for(int j=0;j<columnCount;j++)
                    {
                        String columnName = headerRow.get(j);
                        String columnValue = dataRow.get(j);

                        rowJsonObject.put(columnName, columnValue);
                    }

                    tableJsonObject.put("Row " + i, rowJsonObject);
                }

                // Return string format data of JSONObject object.
                ret = tableJsonObject.toString();

            }
        }
        return ret;
    }


    /* Return a text table string from the string list. */
    private static String getTextTableStringFromList(List<List<String>> dataTable)
    {
        StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();

        if(dataTable != null)
        {
            // Get all row count.
            int rowCount = dataTable.size();

            // Loop in the all rows.
            for(int i=0;i<rowCount;i++)
            {
                // Get each row.
                List<String> row = dataTable.get(i);

                // Get one row column count.
                int columnCount = row.size();

                // Loop in the row columns.
                for(int j=0;j<columnCount;j++)
                {
                    // Get column value.
                    String column = row.get(j);

                    // Append column value and a white space to separate value.
                    strBuf.append(column);
                    strBuf.append("    ");
                }

                // Add a return character at the end of the row. 
                strBuf.append("\r\n");
            }

        }
        return strBuf.toString();
    }

    /* Write string data to a file.*/
    private static void writeStringToFile(String data, String fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get current executing class working directory.
            String currentWorkingFolder = System.getProperty("user.dir");

            // Get file path separator.
            String filePathSeperator = System.getProperty("file.separator");

            // Get the output file absolute path.
            String filePath = currentWorkingFolder + filePathSeperator + fileName;

            // Create File, FileWriter and BufferedWriter object.
            File file = new File(filePath);

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);

            BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            // Write string data to the output file, flush and close the buffered writer object.
            buffWriter.write(data);

            buffWriter.flush();

            buffWriter.close();

            System.out.println(filePath + " has been created.");

        }catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

for more details visit https://www.dev2qa.com/convert-excel-to-json-in-java-example/

Comment: Maybe put Input/OutputStreams into try-with-resource constructs?

Comment: I'd suggest NIO Files#write for writing the JSON to the file.